# functional stateless component get width

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm writing a library, I can't get DOM width because it doesn't have lifecycle method.

If my component has class I can do this

```
var Container = React.createComponent({

  componentDidMount: function () {
    var width = React.findDOMNode(this).offsetWidth;
  },

  render: function () {
    <svg />
  }
});
```

But what if it's a functional, stateless component? how to get the width of an element?

Comment: I think you would have to do the measuring in the component's parent (if the parent is not stateless).

Comment: @Scarysize so the only way is to do that in the container?

Comment: The only clean way I can think of yes. There may be some hacks to work around that, e.g. you could pass a function as a child which is called when the component is rendered and trigger the measuring there.

Answer (score -1):

I am not quite sure, if I got your question right, but how about getting the element like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("someID");
if(element != null)
  console.log(element.offsetWidth);
```

?